# Split chars using the "Enter" key as delimeter

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have some set of `string` values which has `enter` key as a delimeter in between and stored in the database. Now I have to split those string values using the `split` function and save it in an array.

//Code

```
Dim valuesArray as String()= Field.ListOfValues.Split(?)
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, in Windows, lines are terminated with the two-character sequence `<CR><LF>`, you need the [String.Split overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1bwe3zdy.aspx) that splits on strings rather than characters:

```
Dim valuesArray = Field.ListOfValues.Split({vbCrLf}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

Answer (score 2):

The "Enter" key you refer to could possibly be either a Carriage Return, or Line Feed or Both. The following uses [ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx) so this should do what you want and should account for variances in end of line characters

***StreamReader.ReadLine Method***

*Reads a line of characters from the current stream and returns the data as a string.*

*A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a line feed ("\n"), a carriage return ("\r"), or a carriage return immediately followed by a line feed ("\r\n"). The string that is returned does not contain the terminating carriage return or line feed.*

```
    Dim valuesList As New List(Of String)

    Using sr As New StreamReader(New System.IO.MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Field.ListOfValues)))
        Do Until sr.EndOfStream
            valuesList.Add(sr.ReadLine)
        Loop
    End Using

    'If you really want an array convert it to one here:
    Dim valuesArray As String() = valuesList.ToArray
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Enter key= `CChar(vbCrLf)`

//Code

```
Dim valuesArray as String()= Field.ListOfValues.Split(CChar(vbCrLf))
```

Comment: please take a look on the data before you use this - depending on the origin of the data, only vbCr vbLf will be used as linefeed. This depends on the operation system etc.

Comment: You could always use Environment.NewLine instead of vbCrLF

Comment: Do note that `CChar(vbCrLf)` yields the same as `CChar(vbCr)`, i.e., a single CR character. This is probably not what you intended. ([Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy(v=vs.110).aspx): `only first character of a String is converted`)